# How to handle unanswered MSE questions with answers on MO?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, mathoverflow

For reference, I am looking at [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588626/a-combinatorial-identity-involving-generalized-harmonic-numbers) in particular, which mentions obtaining an answer on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226732/a-combinatorial-identity-involving-generalized-harmonic-numbers). I guess the question was posted to MSE first and, perhaps after nudging from other uses, reposted to MO? I'm not too sure, but I don't think the specifics are too important, since I imagine this question is not unique in this respect.

My question is simply thus: how should we handle such questions?

My go-to response was simply a copy-and-paste of the accepted MO answer, posted as community wiki and with a brief blurb at the top attributing it to the responsible user and explaining that it was posted on MO. Or perhaps it should be flagged for deletion? I'm not sure, so I figured I'd ask.

(Of course I also haven't actually done anything as of yet.)

Comment: The post on MSE has a line at the top linking to the answer on MO.  Could that not be put into the answer box (perhaps as Community wiki? though I don't see such an answer getting many upvotes) if your aim is just to remove "unanswered" questoins from the site.

Comment: To my understanding, link-only answers are generally not kosher for a number of reasons, thus why it would be best supplemented perhaps by a copy of the answer itself. At least, in my opinion.

Comment: That's fair.  I think link-only answers are frowned on because of link-rot; something that's not really an issue if the link is to MO and the question has been well-received there.

Comment: You could find some related discussions here on meta. For example, I was able to find these posts: [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9210) and [Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10072)

Comment: It seems to me that if a question is considered on-topic on MO, then it is likely off-topic here, and can reasonably be closed (and maybe deleted).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I have done this a few times (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2503975/72031) for example). In my view the question is on topic here (series stuff) , but a bit specialized (Ramanujan stuff) which was very easily handled on mathoverflow. On the other hand many other questions of same variety (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/907480/72031)) got very good answers on MSE itself. So I believe there are some questions which might be on topic on both MSE and MO.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: however I do understand that the typical MO questions of math research variety don't belong on MSE.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Note the hedge in my comment:   "It seems to me that if a question is considered on-topic on MO, then it is **likely** off-topic here..."  There are exceptions, but, in general the domains of Math SE and MO overlap very little.