# Better praxis: my answer in MO would be good for this question in MSE. "Link to it in a comment" or "copy/paste text"?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

A question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4005409) has no answer yet; and I recalled I've answered a similar question years ago in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71444/7710). I've looked at it and even found it would be good to add a picture to it (and just did it).

This MO-answer would be -so to say- an "indirect answer", or say "an answer to a generalizing of the question". But for the casual reader in MSE as well as for the question at all, it might be more instructive to have that anwer directly copied there instead of a small notice & link in the sequence of comments.

What is the better praxis here?

Comment: My opinion; copy your answer to math.se, but include a note saying it's copied from MO.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - done. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Not the same question, but I'd say related: [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9210)